# running eslint and prettier on save in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Is there a way to run both eslint and prettier on save in vscode? I have the following configuration in settings.json

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
    "source.organizeImports",
    "source.fixAll.eslint"
  ],
```

but some rules from eslint are being overwritten by prettier, anyone had this problem?

Comment: Your ESLint and Prettier configurations may be mutually incompatible, they have very different goals and philosophies. See e.g. https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html.